# Not able to apply margin to div

Tags: html, css

```
<input type="text" id="title" />
<input type="button" id="save_post" class="button" value="Submit" />
<div id="map" style="margin-top:10px;"></div>
```

For some reason there is no margin in the rendered page.

The first `input` is directly to the left of the second `input`, and the `div` is directly under both, with no spacing in between.

I've also tried placing `<br />` tags but that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

CSS

```
.button {
    width: 80px;
    height: 34px;
    border: none;
    background: #673491;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
}

#title {
    height: 30px;
    width: 276px;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
    background: #fff;
    text-indent: 10px;
    color: #999999;
    float: left;
}

#left {
    width: 360px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 7px;
    padding-top: 24px;
}

#content {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}

body {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    color: #999999;
    font-family: arial, verdana;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the value of the `button` class?

Comment: There is other CSS in play. I'll post.

Comment: You might have a float issue with your input CSS - check my answer with the clear:both

Comment: Thanks posting your CSS code. It's the fact you got float left in your button class. Add an empty div with clear:both as style. You should be good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the two inputs in the a div of their own with no styling.

If you are using firefox get the extension [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/downloads/) as it shows you padding and margins etc. Very, very handy tool!

If all else fails. Try a div between the inputs and your div 'map' and put style="clear:both;" also try padding-top instead

Comment: No prob it's the clear fix :) I battled with that for ages once :) you will need to place an empty div with clear every time you have used float

Answer (score 0):

The above code works for me. Try finding another style which is overriding your margin. Or place !important

```
<div id="map" style="margin-top:10px !important;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in your CSS code to see if there is a rule like:

`#map { ...}`

Or try with:

`<div id="map" style="margin-top:10px !important;"></div>`